# 15.04 How to check if Nvidia SLI is enabled w/ proprietary drivers?

Tags: nvidia

With the latest (tested) proprietary Nvidia drivers installed, how can you find out if Nvidia SLI is enabled? Can you check in the "Nvidia X Server Settings" application? Command-line?

(Running Ubuntu 15.04 x64 w/ two Nvidia Geforce 660's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SLI connector is a proprietary link between GPUs that transmits synchronization, display, and pixel data.

The `SLI` connector enables inter-GPU communication of up to 1 Gb/s, consuming no bandwidth over the PCI Express bus.

`SLI` is enabled by setting the `SLI` option in the X configuration file.

The `nvidia-xconfig` utility can be used to set the `SLI` option, rather than modifying the X configuration file by hand.

```
nvidia-xconfig --sli=on
```

The valid values for `SLI` are `Off`, `On`, `Auto`, `AFR`, `SFR`, `AA`, and `AFRofAA`.

For further information, look at [`man nvidia-xconfig`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/nvidia-xconfig.1.html).

## Check if `SLI` is enabled

The only way to check if `SLI` is enabled is by checking first GPU and seeing what it says as the Screen0 it should say your screen model and then `SLI`.

## [Source](http://www.geforce.com/)

Comment: Do you know how to control the fan speed of nvidia graphic card? I searched it, and it seems that they control the fan only at startup. I want to control it in real time. Thanks.